# Hibernate DELETE Statement in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

How to delete a row in JPA? I have found some examples on the internet, but I did  not fina any good solution.

I have tried so far:

```
Session session = null;
Query query1 = null;
Query query2 = null;

String[] parts = userId.split("=");
userId = parts[1];
parts = userId.split(" ");
userId = parts[0];
int intIdUser = Integer.parseInt(userId);

query1= session.getNamedQuery("UserCountry.removeAssoc");
query1.setParameter("userId", userId);
query1.executeUpdate();    

query2= session.getNamedQuery("UserLanguage.removeAssoc");
query2.setParameter("userId", userId);
query2.executeUpdate();
```

But I get HTTP Status 500:

```
java.lang.Exception
com.se.pl.actions.user.UserAction.saveAssoc(UserAction.java:69)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

And the Named Query are:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "UserCountry.removeAssoc", query = "DELETE FROM UserCountry u WHERE u.userId = :userId"),
```

**EDIT:**

Here the error is generated by the invoke method saveAssoc():

```
    public String saveAssoc() throws Exception {
    try {
        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();

        iUserDAO.saveUserAssoc(httpSession.getAttribute("selectedUser").toString(), countryId, langId);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**It goes straight to catch when it reaches query1= session.getNamedQuery("UserCountry.removeAssoc"); line.**

Stack trace:

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.Exception
com.se.pl.actions.user.UserAction.saveAssoc(UserAction.java:69)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:446)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:285)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.

Comment: [Here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete) you have an example.

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with your solution, seems reasonable to me.  Can you post the code that is actually throwing the exception, along with line numbers.

Comment: This is Hibernate, not JPA. Nothing wrong with that, but it is important to name things right! Using a query the way you do is somewhat "working against the tool" when using on object-relationa mapper like hibernate. You should have an `User` object, having 1:n associations to `Country` and `Language` (which should map to a java `List<Country>` and `List<Language>`. Empty these collections and Hibernate will do the trick for you.

Comment: I added an EDIT to my question regarding your comments. Thanks for further help!

Comment: Have you considered using [`CriteriaDelete`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaDelete.html) from the Criteria API? Criteria API is awesome. Highly recommended.